# Can I list my ongoing course project on cv?

Tags: cv

I'm preparing my cv for the Ph.D. applications. Under the 'work in progress' section, I wonder if I can list two essays I'm currently writing for my coursework without mentioning they are actually assignments for the course. The topic of the essays is relevant to the Ph.D. direction I'm applying to.

Also, If I'm currently revising a preprint (which has been listed in 'preprints and publications' section), can I still mention that under 'work in progress' section? I'm thinking about presenting something like:

**Work in progress**

- An essay on [topic A]
- An essay on [topic B]
- A preprint revision on [topic C]

Does this seem appropriate? Should I be specific in describing those topics? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, what is on your CV is up to you. But consider what you will say if asked about your "essays" in an interview. It is probably better to be very honest about such things at the start. If those essays were potentially publishable listing them without comment would seem more open. But it is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes I think I might extend those essays after my coursework and prepare to submit them so that's why I don't want to mention its for my class.